# configurations eclipse

Tags: php, python, eclipse, configuration

I want to run php or python scripts from eclipse that will create folders and files and give them content. I think I know what to write for the php or python code but I am having trouble on what I need to do in eclipse to run my script. I would also like to provide my script with arguments such as folder names through a prompt on the eclipse side.

I think I have to do something from Run-> External Tools -> External Tools Configuration.

Please Help, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't have to do anything to eclipse, or any editor, if php\python is installed you can call them from the command line.

Comment: I understand that but is there not a way of running through eclipse?

Comment: i use zend studio, based on eclipse, it has run>run as>php script

Comment: @Dagon YES! Thank you! The regular eclipse also has run_as php script.  This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Any thoughts on how I can provide arguments and call specific functions using this method?

Comment: it just calls the script via the command line executable and parse the output, so you cant, you can of course just open a command prompt and do it that way with your variables

Comment: @milan  there may be "run configuration" in the run menu (never noticed that before) :-)